# sending data from android to web without being able to look it up

Tags: java, android, dropbox, google-docs

I am making an android app for a `survey`. The answers are saved in a `file`, and that file should be sent to the web, so we can analyse the data. I am searching for a way to put the data on the web, in such a way that only I can access it.

I've tried google doc's, but it seems to me that if too many people upload their data at the same time, some data might get `overwritten`.

I've also tried `dropbox`, but the problem is the `authentication` step. Since every person would have emailadres and password, everyone would have access to all data, which should not be possible (unless there is a way to authenticate in the code, but I haven't found anything on that).

Does anyone have an idea what I can do? Thank you!

Comment: You have many options to store files: upload to FTP server, upload to cloud (Drive, Dropbox, ...), write you own web service (preferred). And set filenames as current timestamps so files won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a Google Document directly.  With a lot of traffic you'll definitely get overwritten data.  You're also vulnerable to someone messing with the data since you'll need the document to be public so people can edit it.

What you want to do is create a [Google Form](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html) and then have your application `POST` the data to that.  Google will handle making sure that no data is overwritten for you.